# How to integrate two separate Flask apps

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am making a web interface for the Anki Vector robot using Flask called VectorCloud. VectorCloud uses code provided from Anki's SDK to send commands to the robot via wifi connection. Included in the SDK is a Flask app named 'remote_control.py' my goal is to integrate the remote_control.py app with VectorCloud as another page on the interface.

My question is: what is the best/easiest/practical way to go about doing this? I tried running them at the same time and as long as I change the port number and run them in separate console windows it works, but if I try to call remote_control.py from VectorCloud I get err #88 (I've tried pretty much every os and subprocess commands I could find.) I've also tried copy/pasting the relevant code into VectorCloud and found that that's going to be long tedious process of testing bit by bit. Anything I'm not thinking of here?

Here some screenshots of the file structure:
[VectorCloud file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j5R7.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Application Dispatching](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appdispatch/) to give them different paths or subdomains:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from VectorCloud import app as vc
from your_app import app as my_app

application = DispatcherMiddleware(my_app, {
    '/vc':     vc
})
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!! I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Yes I did! The first thing I did was edit the remote control app to be a single python file (it was previously two files the flask_helpers.py and remote_control.py - though I learned later this step was unnecessary). Then I made it a  flask blueprint and removed all functions related to opening the browser, declaring the flask instance, and running flask, I also set the ‘/’ route of remote control app to be ‘/control’.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/

here's my project for the file structure:
https://github.com/rmountjoy92/VectorCloud

Answer (score 0):

Maybe could fork the remote_control.py from the SDK and wrap it in a REST based API.  That would seem to me to be the best approach if you are looking to communicate between apps.